# Can't run selenium test through Jenkins in Docker

Tags: selenium, ubuntu, docker, jenkins, virtual-machine

So I have VM with Ubuntu on it. The host is on Win10. Inside this VM I installed a docker where I pulled jenkins and installed selenium plugin for jenkins.
I could reached a selenium node from win10. But when I try to launch a test from my IDE :

```
val cap: DesiredCapabilities =  DesiredCapabilities.chrome()
cap.setBrowserName("chrome")
webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.10.223:4445/wd/hub/"), cap)
go to "https://www.google.com"
```

I have this error and i don't understand why...

```
Exception encountered when invoking run on a nested suite - Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:08.936Z'
System info: host: '2d3135afb490', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-24-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Command duration or timeout: 101 milliseconds
```

Am I doing something wrong ? or am I missing some configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

Docker Containers do not have a Desktop(and your selenium process is running inside such a container if I udnerstood it right) so they will not run UI tests. Your chances are:

1. Use PhantomJS Driver. This is a browser that won't render anything and does not need a Desktop. *Disclaimer: Tried it in Headless(Desktopless) sessions but not on Docker*
2. Try to Hack your Docker image and create an [X Desktop Session.](https://forums.docker.com/t/does-it-possible-to-run-gui-base-desktop-application-on-dockers/13769/5)

Comment: I don't need a desktop to run some test, if i'm not wrong. There is xvfb plugin in jenkins to run headless tests. So why do i need a desktop ?

Comment: but that is most probably helping you in an OS environment. Inside docker you do not have out-of-the-box the possibility for xvfb. Did you try this: https://github.com/auth0/docker-xvfb ?